# SQL Server bad performance with a lot of ORs and repeating criteria using UPPER()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-performance

A software generates a lot of these, non optimal, queries:

```
SELECT
    <List of Columns>
FROM <Table>
WHERE(
      ([COL1] = UPPER('CONST_VALUE') AND [COL2] = UPPER('v1')) OR
      ([COL1] = UPPER('CONST_VALUE') AND [COL2] = UPPER('v2')) OR
      ([COL1] = UPPER('CONST_VALUE') AND [COL2] = UPPER('v4')) OR
      ([COL1] = UPPER('CONST_VALUE') AND [COL2] = UPPER('v6')) OR
      ([COL1] = UPPER('CONST_VALUE') AND [COL2] = UPPER('v8')) OR
      <...>
     )
```

Execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJGtaBzSU

Executing this query results in an Index Seek which takes about 1s to execute. Refactoring the query to the following statement results in an execution time of 3ms:

```
SELECT
    <List of Columns>
FROM <Table>
WHERE([COL1] = UPPER('CONST_VALUE') AND (
    [COL2] = UPPER('v1') OR
    [COL2] = UPPER('v2') OR
    [COL2] = UPPER('v4') OR
    [COL2] = UPPER('v6') OR
    [COL2] = UPPER('v8') OR
    <...>
    ))
```

The indexes look optimal afaik, an index on COL1 and COL2 including all selected other columns. Since we can't change the software for now, is there a way to speed up the execution time? Adding a different kind of index. I was also thinking about something like query rewrite or the like, but couldn't find such a thing in SQL Server.

Comment: You can use `in` operator. Something like `where col1='const_value' and col2 in ('v1','v2','v3')`. It is better readable but internally compiled into your 2nd example.

Comment: As you also mention this doesn't fix the problem about the performance. For the example above i chose to keep the better performing statement as close as possible to the original one to make the problem more obvious.

Comment: Your options are limited if you can't change the query. Have you tried an index on COL! and COL2 with <List of Columns> as included columns?

Comment: I think that's what I said we already have, or do you mean something else? Index with two columns, COL1 and COL2, all other selected columns are included in this index.

Comment: Have you examine the _actual execution plan_? See [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question. Are the index statistics current? See [`update statistics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/update-statistics-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for more information.

Comment: Updated the statistics (no change) and added the plan (https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJGtaBzSU)

Comment: It is the use of `UPPER` that causes the problem, without that it collapses the predicates down fine. For some reason it doesn't constant fold that function and presumably just treats it as though the different references to  `UPPER('000049')` might not evaluate to the same thing

Comment: @Martin Smith: Oh yes.. that's it. Looks like a strange problem of SQL Server. I didn't include that in the example because it seemed to make it more complicated than needed - sorry for that! Will update the question later. Thanks again!

Comment: The problem is that without the constant folding it can't just blindly do repeated seeks. UPPER('a') and UPPER('A') both evaluate to the same thing but rows matching that shouldn't be returned doubled up. So it needs a step for duplicate removal. Your manual rewrite does that with a merge interval. Not sure if this is not available when two columns may vary

Comment: This is the correct answer so.... otherwise i can do it myself...

Comment: Do you have any options that can affect the query generated by the application? E.g. removing the UPPER as unless you are on a case sensitive collation this is not needed anyway

Comment: Removing the UPPER is much easier than refactoring the whole statement, so we might try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to make changes to the query then remove the `UPPER` - This can be straightforwardly removed if you are on a case insensitive collation (by far the most common case) - otherwise you will need to add logic to ensure the values are uppercased before being added to the query. `UPPER` is not constant folded and can give worse plans than simple string literals as shown in the various examples below.

Example Data

```
CREATE TABLE [Table]
(
[COL1] VARCHAR(20),
[COL2] VARCHAR(10),
PRIMARY KEY ([COL1],[COL2])
)

INSERT INTO [Table]
SELECT TOP 100 'CONST_VALUE',  CONCAT('v', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID))
FROM sys.all_columns
```

**Query 1**

```
SELECT *
FROM [Table]
WHERE(
      ([COL1] = 'CONST_VALUE' AND [COL2] = 'V1') OR
      ([COL1] = 'CONST_VALUE' AND [COL2] = 'V1') OR
      ([COL1] = 'CONST_VALUE' AND [COL2] = 'V4') 
     )
```

The execution plan for this has an index seek operator. Looking at the properties of the plan shows the seek actually contains two different multi column seek predicates (not three seeks. it would be an error to perform the 'V1' seek twice and return those rows twice even though it appears in the `WHERE` clause twice)

[image]

**Query 2**

```
SELECT *
FROM [Table] 
WHERE(
      ([COL1] = 'CONST_VALUE' AND [COL2] = UPPER('v1')) OR
      ([COL1] = 'CONST_VALUE' AND [COL2] = UPPER('V1')) OR
      ([COL1] = 'CONST_VALUE' AND [COL2] = UPPER('v2')) 
     )
```

This execution plan looks promising but on closer inspection the seek is only on the single column `COL1` - as all rows in the table have the value `'CONST_VALUE'` in this case the seek achieves nothing and all the work is done with a residual predicate.

[image]

**Query 3**

```
SELECT *
FROM [Table] WITH (FORCESEEK)
WHERE(
      ([COL1] = 'CONST_VALUE' AND [COL2] = UPPER('v1')) OR
      ([COL1] = 'CONST_VALUE' AND [COL2] = UPPER('V1')) OR
      ([COL1] = 'CONST_VALUE' AND [COL2] = UPPER('v2')) 
     )
```

This is the same as previous but with a `FORCESEEK` hint added. The results of `UPPER` are not constant folded at compile time for some reason so it adds extra operators to the plan to evaluate the `UPPER` and then collapse down the identical results to perform the two needed multi column index seeks.

[image]

**Query 4**

```
SELECT *
FROM [Table] 
WHERE(
      ([COL1] = UPPER('CONST_VALUE') AND [COL2] = UPPER('v1')) OR
      ([COL1] = UPPER('CONST_VALUE') AND [COL2] = UPPER('V1')) OR
      ([COL1] = UPPER('CONST_VALUE') AND [COL2] = UPPER('v2')) 
     )
```

Now SQL Server gives up and just gives a scan

[image]

### Query 5

```
SELECT *
FROM [Table] 
WHERE [COL1] = UPPER('CONST_VALUE') AND  
(
      [COL2] = UPPER('v1') OR
      [COL2] = UPPER('V1') OR
      [COL2] = UPPER('v2') 
)
```

This rewrite gives the same execution plan as Query 2 - with a seek on `Col1` and residual predicate on `Col2`, this is not useful with my example data but would be with more realistic cases.

### Query 6

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.all_objects
where 'v1' <> 'v1'
```

SQL Server detects the contradiction at compile time and gives a very simple plan

[image]

### Query 7

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.all_objects
where UPPER('v1') <> UPPER('v1')
```

Despite the fact that the expressions are deterministic and have exactly the same input values no contradiction detection occurs

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is not a lot the query optimizer can do in this case. You fall into the trap similar to IN with many arguments -> fallback is table scan.

Put up a table variable with the comparison values, 2 fields and primary key on them, then you can use that table variable in a join and the index on the primary key provides statistics for the query optimizer to work with.